# MYSQL display groups that do not contain certain value in one column

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have 2 tables `customer_address_entity`

```
entity_id | foo | bar
----------------------
1         | bla | bla
2         | bla | bla
3         | bla | bla
```

and `customer_address_entity_varchar`

```
value_id | attribute_id |entity_id | value
-------------------------------------------------
1        | 21           | 1        | something_1
2        | 22           | 1        | anything_1
3        | 31           | 1        | whatever_1
4        | 21           | 2        | something_2
5        | 22           | 2        | anything_2
6        | 21           | 3        | something_3
7        | 31           | 3        | whatever_3
```

and I want to select all the elements in `customer_address_entity` that do not have any attribute_id = 31 value in `customer_address_entity_varchar`.

For example, `customer_address_entity` entity_id = 2 have `customer_address_entity_varchar` attribute_id values of 21 and 22 but not 31. So I want to select this one.

just now I'm joining both of the tables, and grouping them by `entity_id`, but

```
SELECT cae.`entity_id`, caev.`attribute_id`, caev.`value`
FROM `customer_address_entity` AS `cae`
INNER JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `caev`
ON cae.`entity_id`=caev.`entity_id`
GROUP BY cae.`entity_id`;
```

example of joined tables with GROUP_BY:

```
entity_id | attribute_id | value
---------------------------------------
1         | 21           | something_1
2         | 21           | something_2
3         | 21           | something_3
```

I'm stuck here, as I don't know how to select the group that do not have 31 in attribute_id.

desired result:

```
entity_id | attribute_id | value
---------------------------------------
2         | 21           | something_2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result using not exists clause. Try the below query it is checking every entity id for attribute id = 31.

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer_address_entity_varchar t1
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM customer_address_entity_varchar t2 WHERE t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id
and attribute_id = 31  )
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use aggregation to find the matching groups:

```
SELECT t1.entity_id, t1.attribute_id, t1.value
FROM customer_address_entity_varchar t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT entity_id
    FROM customer_address_entity_varchar
    GROUP BY entity_id
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN attribute_id = 31 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
) t2
    ON t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id;
```

If you don't want the full matching records from the `customer_address_entity_varchar` table, and instead you just want the `entity_id` values, then just use the above subquery aliased as `t2`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT cae.`entity_id`, caev.`attribute_id`, caev.`value`
FROM `customer_address_entity` AS `cae`
INNER JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `caev`
ON cae.`entity_id`=caev.`entity_id`
where cae.entity_id not in (select caev2.entity_id  from `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `caev2` where caev2.attribute_id = 31)
```

You need to remove all the entity_ids from the first query, which have attribute_id = 31